# Email Parsing with apex class

Tags: apex, email, string

Anybody having knowledge regarding the Email Parsing??
I have a requirement that i receive data from email and i need to split it.
for ex: *Category : (Some Data)
        *Type : (Some Data)
I need to separate the data accordingly and store the same.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have your [inbound email service](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm) set up, which is pretty easy to do if you just follow the docs, you'll need to write an [inbound email handler class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm) to process inbound email objects using the [inbound email class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm#apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound).

You'll then want to set up a means to split your email body. Unless there's a common delimiter that you know you can count on, you'll want to use the [Matcher Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm) along with [RegEx](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to separate the data strings into Capture Groups for further processing. I've linked you to a site that will help you set up your RegEx expression.

Once you have the capture groups (strings), you can use various string methods as required from the [string class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_methods_system_string) to do what you need to get your data, such as splitting the strings using the colon following Category: or whatever strategy you feel makes the most sense to you then assigning the value to your field or a list for later dml processing.

There are plenty of examples of inbound email handlers for processing various types of data if you google them, so I won't include any code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own email handler. You'll find more information [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com) and [here](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/12/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com/)

If you need to process the content of the email, you can do it in the handleInboundEmail method, using regex or whatever you need

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

We decided on using [Parserr.com](http://parserr.com) finally to do this after finding this stackexchange post a few months ago.

Our case was a bit different as we had to extract row data (lead per row) from Excel using Parserr. But I believe they do email parsing too.

Full disclosure - through talking to the founder of the business, Im happy to vouch for them and help them along. Which is what Im doing here.